# Dynamic element from array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dynamic, element

I want to dynamically update a element whenever the array it is based from changes.

```
  //Dynamic Array - depositInfo[0] looks like:
  //[{"tsR":1648183525,"durR":30,"amtR":10000000000000000}]

  let depositInfo = [];

  const depositCard = (card, index, amtR) => {
    return (
      <div key={index}>
        <Text strong>
          Value that doesn't update!: 
          {card.tsR}
          {parseFloat(card.tsR)}
          {JSON.stringify(depositInfo[index].tsR)}
          <p />
          Values that do update!: 
          {JSON.stringify(depositInfo[index])}
          <p />
        </Text>
      </div>
    );
  };
```

The element is rendering on the page before the values are dynamically retrieved into the array, rendering it blank. After the array updates, the values on the page remain the same except for the ones generated by `{JSON.stringify(depositInfo[index])}`

How do I update the depositCard info every time depositInfo[] changes/is updated?

Edit:
Also why does depositInfo[index].tsR return a blank value when depositInfo[index] works fine?

Comment: If this is reactjs / redux, please add the specific tag (as this is not plain JavaScript), and remove the more generic tags.

Comment: if `depositInfo` changes and you need your component to reflect that, you need to use React state for the value.

Comment: If you would like to update your UI based on your data during runtime, I suggest using a reactive framework like React or Vue

Comment: 1) _depositInfo[0] looks like [...]_ --> this means that the element at index `0` of the array `depositInfo` is an array (& it is this array whose element/s is/are object/s with props such as `tsR`, etc). 2) _ Also why does `depositInfo[index].tsR` return a blank value_ --> because there is no prop called `tsR` in the array (we say at point 1). Try: `depositInfo[index][0].tsR`. It should show the `tsR` prop's value.

Comment: depositInfo[index][0].tsR works great, Thanks!

Comment: Please exercise caution as using `depositInfo[index][0]` implies one is always looking only for the object at index `0`. Two problems may occur. 1) There may be no object at index `0`. For this, please use: `depositInfo[index]?.[0]`. 2) There may be other objects in the array (such as objects at index 1, 2, 3, etc) and none of those will be considered.